# Not getting Required Output

Tags: java, arrays

I have this code below: If I call my object statement like this I get this.

**Output** below:

> trafficqueue.TrafficQueue$Car@1b26af3
>
> trafficqueue.TrafficQueue$Car@8b819f

```
public class TrafficQueue {
    private Car[] carArray;
    private int numberOfcarsInQueue;
    private int f = 0;
    
    public TrafficQueue(int numberOfcarsInQueue){
        carArray = new Car[numberOfcarsInQueue];
    
    
    }
    private static class Car {
        private String make;
        private String colour;

        public Car(String make, String colour) {
            this.make = make;
            this.colour = colour;
        }

        public String getMake(){

            return make;
        }
          
      
    
    } ;
    
    
    public void add(Car car){
        carArray[numberOfcarsInQueue] = car;
        numberOfcarsInQueue ++;
    
    }
    public String toString()
    {
      String result = "";

      for (int scan=0; scan < numberOfcarsInQueue; scan++) 
         result = result + carArray[scan].toString() + "\n";

      return result;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        
        
        TrafficQueue queueLane1 = new TrafficQueue(10);
        Car carT = new Car("Toyota", "Red");
        Car carE = new Car ("Jaguar","Red");
        queueLane1.add(carT);
        queueLane1.add(carE);

        System.out.println(""+queueLane1.toString());
        System.out.println(queueLane1);
        
        System.out.println("Number of Cars in Queue"+ "=" + queueLane1.getNumberOfCarsInQueue());
    }
    
}
```

I have tried using the `java.util.arrays.toString` but to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your question? Be more specific on what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output that you're getting is produced by calling `toString` on the `TrafficQueue` object i.e. this method:

```
public String toString() {
    String result = "";

    for (int scan = 0; scan < numberOfcarsInQueue; scan++)
        result = result + carArray[scan].toString() + "\n";

    return result;
}
```

Let's examine the above method.

The above method calls `carArray[scan].toString()`. `carArray[scan]` is an instance of `Car`. What you're doing here is essentially calling `toString` on a `Car`.

Did you define a `toString` method for `Car`? Nope. That's why the default `toString` is called. That's why you see outputs like this

> trafficqueue.TrafficQueue$Car@1b26af3

If you want a human readable string representation of `Car`, just override `toString`:

```
public String toString() {
    return colour + " " + getMake();
}
```

Your whole `Car` class should look like this:

```
private static class Car {
    private String make;
    private String colour;

    public Car(String make, String colour) {
        this.make = make;
        this.colour = colour;
    }

    public String getMake() {

        return make;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return colour + " " + getMake();
    }
}
```